# How do I put data from an API call into a list in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am making an app that will list the rankings, name, points, and country of tennis players. I get that information from an API call.

This is the API call:

```
import Foundation

let url = "https://tennisapi1.p.rapidapi.com/api/tennis/rankings/atp/?rapidapi-key=APIKEY"

func getData(from url: String) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("something went wrong")
            return
        }
        
        var result: RankingsResponse?
        do {
            result = try JSONDecoder().decode(RankingsResponse.self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
            print("failed to convert \(error)")
        }
        guard let json = result else {
            return
        }
        
        result?.rankings.forEach {
            print("Name:", $0.rowName)
            print("Ranking:", $0.ranking)
            print( "Points:", $0.points)
            print("Country:", $0.team.country.name)
            print("")
            
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

import Foundation

// MARK: - RankingsResponse
struct RankingsResponse: Codable {
    let rankings: [Ranking]
    let updatedAtTimestamp: Int
}

// MARK: - Ranking
struct Ranking: Codable {
    let bestRanking: Int
    let bestRankingDateTimestamp: Int?
    let country: RankingCountry
    let id, points, previousPoints, previousRanking: Int
    let ranking: Int
    let rowName: String
    let team: Team
    let tournamentsPlayed, type: Int
}

// MARK: - RankingCountry
struct RankingCountry: Codable {
}

// MARK: - Team
struct Team: Codable {
    let country: TeamCountry
    let disabled: Bool?
    let gender: Gender
    let id: Int
    let name, nameCode: String
    let national: Bool
    let ranking: Int
    let shortName, slug: String
    let type, userCount: Int
}

// MARK: - TeamCountry
struct TeamCountry: Codable {
    let alpha2, name: String
}

enum Gender: String, Codable {
    case m = "M"
}
```

To test if my API call function `getData()` works, I made a button in ContentView that when clicked, runs the function `getData()` and prints the results in the console. That works, but I do not know how to put the results into a list in ContentView.

This is my ContentView code right now:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            NavigationView {
                Button("Print Rankings") {
                    getData(from: url)
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Rankings")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to read some tutorials on SwiftUI -- you'll learn about `@State` or an `ObservableObject` with `@Published`, both of which could be useful here. You can also learn about the more modern async/await way to interact with `URLSession`

Comment: Yes as jnpdx has pointed that is the right approach and in case you want to load that URL when the view first appears you could it inside `.task { //your logic to hit API } on your `ContentView`